# horizontal scroll binding in vim

Tags: vim

I'm using `VIm 7.3` to edit 5 files side-by-side with `vsplit`, `set scrollbind` and `set nowrap`, it's quite useful, works well for vertical scroll, but the horizontal scrolling don't be sync.

There is a option to activate horizontal scroll bind sync too ?

Comment: If nobody can help on Super User it might be worth trying http://vi.stackexchange.com/ instead (I only came across it a month ago).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option that controls that is 'scrollopt'. It is set to "ver,jump" by default; you want to add "hor", e.g.,

```
:set scrollopt+=hor
```

See

```
:help 'scrollopt'
```